# CSS background banner for text over circle image

Tags: css, image, background

I need a CSS magic, explain
I've this image

[image]

and I want dinamically add a background stripe like this:

but with css, because sometimes the text is too long for one row and go to a new line...

[image]

These are the css classes user for make text overlap the image:

```
.image-container {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.text-container {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 999;
    margin: 0 auto;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 41%;
    text-align: center; 
    width: 100%; 
    font-size: 24px;
}
```

Thank you very much

Answer (score -1):

If changing your texts shorter makes your problem resolve add these styles to your text:

```css
overflow: hidden;
max-width: as much as you need to make your txt short;
white-space: nowrap;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
```

Comment: I don't know why you need opacity?
share codes with us to help if you want to please.